# Using categories and pages in menus

Tags: categories, menus, permalinks, pages

I've got a problem with mixing categories and pages within menus. As a fictional example:

```
- About us (custom page template)
    -- What we do (page)
    -- Key staff (page)
    -- CEO blog (category)
    -- Contact details (custom page template)
```

The problem I have is the URL structure for the category doesn't follow the same URL pattern as the pages:

```
-About us /about-us/
    -- What we do  /about-us/what-we-do/
    -- Key staff  /about-us/key-staff/
    -- CEO blog  /ceo-blog/
    -- Contact details  /about-us/contact/
```

The CEO blog category is the problem. I don't like the inconsistent URL structure and this also causes some issues with the sub-menu display. I've looked at re-writing the category slug but I can't get it to work. I've also looked at custom taxonomies but re-writing the slug with that has caused permalink issues with the sub-pages (ie: What we do, etc).

This has come up on a few sites now. I know it is easy to have categories as top level sections but it isn't always practical. What I want to do is have the URL structure consistent os the CEO blog would be /about-us/ceo-blog/ and work functionally as a category.

I wonder if the way to solve it is to use categories for the whole section with custom category templates (parent and child templates). It feels a bit inelegant though.

How do others resolve mixing content like this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is "CEO blog" an actual category or is that your Default Blog? If it's your default blog you could just make your blog a subpage under About Us I believe.

Comment: CEO blog is a category. I'm not sure what you mean by Default Blog. I can create the custom menu no problem, the issue is the URL structure is different for different content types (page, category).